# jQuery on event handler losing scope of parent object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object that has multiple functions being registered to events on page load. This seems to be working fine. However, I am having an issue getting the scope of the object once the event happens. `this` seems to only pull in the element that is being triggered by the event. I was wondering if anyone could help and tell me where I went wrong?

**EDIT 1**

I felt that code snippet was pretty concise to the problem. However, I can see where my question may be perceived as lazy.

I have an object that has multiple functions triggered off of events that are dynamically being wired up on load which can be seen here:

```
var collection = function() {
    var _c = {};
    _c.el = '#container',
    _c.buildItems = function(){
        var $el = $('#content2');
        var template = Handlebars.compile($("#tpl-collection-item-row").html());
        var data = [
            {id: 1, val: 'test 1', text: 'this is a test... 1'},
            {id: 2, val: 'test 2', text: 'this is a test... 2'},
            {id: 3, val: 'test 3', text: 'this is a test... 3'},
        ];

        $el.append(template(data));
    },
    _c.clickStuff = function() {
        alert("hey!");
    },
    _c.moreClicking = function() {
        alert("i knew this would work");
    },
    _c.events = [
        {target: '.row', event: 'click', func: 'clickStuff'},
        {target: '#gettingIt', event: 'click', func: 'moreClicking'}
    ],
    _c.initialize = function() {
        var _this = this;
        $.each(this.events, function(){
            var func = _this[this.func]
            $(_this.el).on(this.event, this.target, func);
        });
    },
    _c.render = function() {
        this.initialize();
        this.buildItems();
    }
    return _c;
}
```

`_c.buildItems` is a function that is called to trigger my handlebars template from `_c.render()`. Prior to this happening I am calling a function to wire up events listed in my `_c.events` array that take the `target` object and the type of `event` happening and mapping to the `func` name within my object. This is happening in my `_c.initialize` function.

The events seem to be working perfectly fine. However, I am unsure how to get the scope of my `collection` function from within functions like _c.clickStuff when they are triggered. I am unsure how to do this and it would be great if someone can explain to me where I went wrong?

Here is a fiddle of my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/0s8vb8m3/3/

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include 
the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary 
to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem 
statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and 
Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @j08691 - please see my updated question to hopefully satisfy the requirements and remove your motion to close my question. Thanks...

Comment: Sorry, no. You can just take all the code from your fiddle and put in in your question in an embedded stack snippet. Then I'll retract the close vote.

Comment: Why do you need to get the scope that you are in?  It's already in the scope of collection.  You can access anything in your same scope already.  As such you don't need `var _this = this;`.  Just use `_c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just reference the `_c` in your code as it is in the scope of your "collection" function.

```js
 var collection = function() {
     var _c = {
         el: '#container'
     };

     _c.buildItems = function() {
         var $el = $('#content2');
         var template = Handlebars.compile($("#tpl-collection-item-row").html());
         var data = [{
             id: 1,
             val: 'test 1',
             text: 'this is a test... 1'
         }, {
             id: 2,
             val: 'test 2',
             text: 'this is a test... 2'
         }, {
             id: 3,
             val: 'test 3',
             text: 'this is a test... 3'
         }];

         $el.append(template(data));
     };

     _c.clickStuff = function() {
         console.log(_c.el);
     };

     _c.moreClicking = function() {
         alert("i knew this would work");
     };

     _c.events = [{
         target: '.row',
         event: 'click',
         func: 'clickStuff'
     }, {
         target: '#gettingIt',
         event: 'click',
         func: 'moreClicking'
     }];

     _c.initialize = function() {
         $.each(_c.events, function(index, event) {
             var func = _c[event.func];
             $(_c.el).on(event.event, event.target, func);
         });
     };

     _c.render = function() {
         _c.initialize();
         _c.buildItems();
     };

     return _c;
 }

 var c = collection();

 c.initialize();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div class="row">Blah1</div>
    <div class="row">Blah2</div>
    <div class="row">Blah3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah sorry for the confusion. I was not having issues accessing it from `_c.initialize`, but having issues when the events that I have been registering were triggered. So for example... Clicking `.row` triggers my `_c.clickStuff()` function, and in there I cannot access my `collection` function.

Comment: What inside the clickStuff are you trying to access that you cannot? @scapegoat17

Comment: I am unable to access `_c.el` from your example. or even `_c` in general